Unexpected KW_BODY wile starting syslog-ng via AWS/Fargate
While looking into setting up a log forwarded with syslog-ng as a Fargate service, I've ran into an issue where I'm able to start this up locally on my laptop, but not in AWS/Fargate. The error I'm getting is:
20 Error parsing within destination, syntax error, unexpected KW_BODY, expecting ')' in /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf:26:7-26:11:
21 destination d_datadog {
22 http(
23 url("https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/api/v2/logs?ddsource=`DD_SOURCE`&ddtags=test:test}")
24 method("POST")
25 headers("Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json", "DD-API-KEY: `DD_API_KEY`")
26----> body("<${PRI}>1 ${ISODATE} ${HOST:--} ${PROGRAM:--} ${PID:--} ${MSGID:--} ${SDATA:--} $MSG\n")
26----> ^^^^
27 );
28 };

The full syslog-ng.conf is:
@version: 4.8
@include "scl.conf"

source s_network {
  tcp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(601));
};

source s_local {
  internal();
};

destination d_stdout {
  file("/dev/stdout");
};

destination d_local {
  file("/var/log/messages");
  file("/var/log/messages-kv.log" template("$ISODATE $HOST $(format-welf --scope all-nv-pairs)\n") frac-digits(3));
};

destination d_datadog {
  http(
      url("https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/api/v2/logs?ddsource=`DD_SOURCE`&ddtags=test:test")
      method("POST")
      headers("Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json", "DD-API-KEY: `DD_API_KEY`")
      body("<${PRI}>1 ${ISODATE} ${HOST:--} ${PROGRAM:--} ${PID:--} ${MSGID:--} ${SDATA:--} $MSG\n")
  );
};

log {
  source(s_network);
  source(s_local);
  destination(d_local);
  destination(d_stdout);
  destination(d_datadog);
};

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!

The problem turned out to be the fact that I didn't update the SecretsManager secret for DD_API_KEY leaving it as default.
The default auto-generated secret was (this is not at all sensitive):
QH{lfV8Rt~R"%zkq^Xd#cH_>{='vKW/Q
This didn't play well with syslog-ng.conf and the error messages were VERY cryptic.
